Table to Geodatabase script in ArcGIS Pro failing with error 000210
After adding a .csv file (Some_Table.csv) to a project in ArcGIS Pro, I need to save the file to a .dbf file. The Table to Geodatabase script runs without creating any output whatsoever, and I get the following "warning":
Failed to convert Some_Table.csv.  ERROR 000210: Cannot create output C:\Users\fakepath\UPDATED\Some_Table_csv.dbf
Failed to execute (CopyRows).
My research revealed that antivirus settings could be causing this, and so could permission problems. I set the antivirus to make an exception for Some_Table.csv, then tried running ArcGIS Pro as an administrator, as well as saving the output to different locations, but the result is the same. There is an element of the file path ("fakepath" above) that has a space in it (not an underscore); could this be causing the problem? Any ideas what else could be causing this, and what are some possible workarounds?

I would have removed the space from the path before turning off a virus scanner. Of course, I wouldn't ever have a space in a folder or file name to begin with.

I have now tried writing the .dbf file to another location, without spaces in the file path, and the result is the same. So, apparently not caused by antivirus, permissions, or spaces in the file path.

The only explanation I can think of is that I am using a different, newer version of ArcGIS Pro than either you or the example I'm trying to follow. In my version (3.3.1), Table to Table is nowhere to be found, and I have just learned that it is deprecated, and its functionality taken over by the Export Table tool. I ran that tool, specifying my project's default geodatabase rather than a folder as the output location (in the example I'm following, apparently a new geodatabase was created in the folder, the new .dbf file its only content). So far, everything seems to work.

Table to Geodatabase creates file or enterprise geodatabase tables using the source name(s) in the targeted Workspace. You cannot specify the output FGDB or EGDB table name, much less a name with a forbidden character  (the former because it doesn't have owners, and the latter because you can only create as the connection username/schema). The parser can't find the "dbf" table owned by user "Some_Table_csv" in an non-connection path (the directory path is not a workspace, and the feature dataset name contains a forbidden character).
If you use Table to Table you'll be permitted to create an output dBase file.

"Some_Table_csv" is not the user's name. The user's name is hidden in the fakepath part of the file path (and is the part that contains the space).

You can't create a geodatabase table with a dot in the name. It doesn't matter how you obfuscate the path, it is simply not permitted. Ever. Just like you can't create a shapefile inside a geodatabase. The command has multiple supported outputs, and your use case is not one of them. That's what the 000210 error tells you. The only way the dot in the table name could be legal is if it were a EGDB schema, but that command does not support creation with a schema in the name.
